# Deploy aspx page as part of a Sharepoint 2010 Feature

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to find a way to deploy pre-built .aspx pages as part of a Sharepoint 2010 Feature. 
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about application pages then best way to do it is just add a mapped folder to the Layouts directory in your SharePoint project by right clicking on the project and selecting Add -> SharePoint Mapped Folder.

Create a folder for your application under Layouts and add your aspx to this folder. Your aspx will automatically get deployed with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

another option is to add the page via a module. 
try this example: http://blog.beckybertram.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=71

the advantage of this option is, you can use a custom site-template and install your own webparts on the new page

Answer (score 0):

```
<Module Name="Pages" Url=""  Path=""  >
<File Path="Pages\Print.aspx" Url="Print.aspx" Type="Ghostable" NavBarHome="True" />
</Module>
```